# Firebase custom event parameters show up in the Stream View but not on the dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I added a custom event with parameters to Firebase. The parameter shows up in stream view ( events in the last 30 mins) but not in the dashboard and filters. I did check the answers on this subject so here is some more information.

Number of users > 10. 
The parameter has been added to parameter reporting too.
I see a count of the event , its only the parameter that does not show up.

Comment: Some more information. I added audiences for the event parameter values ( my event is for eg. object_touched and the parameter is object name). So I added an audience for events with each object name and I now get the custom parameters listed like so                                                                                 Object name           count                number of users.                                         It seems that the custom event parameters work only when audiences are defined. I want them to work without defining audiences as setting up the audience is tedious.

Comment: Is there any progress here since I have the same problem. I can't see the event-parameter in the dashboard that I'm logging. Except for the Stream-View, they are displayed there live actually.